# Cannot find property length of undefined - MEAN Stack web app on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: javascript, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mean

This may be a simple fix but I've been digging at this for a day and a half now and I can't figure out why this won't work. It worked the other day on the EC2 server and the files that are throwing the error haven't been changed at all.

The exact same file structure works in windows, however does not work when I migrate the files to the ec2 instance. I'm installing the exact same dependencies from the package.json file.

I get a deprecation warning for the native mpromise file, but that happens on both systems. When I run the seed file (seed/engagementPhotoSeed.js) using node, the database populates in windows, but doesn't on the linux system.

I then manually added the MongoDB entries, when I run npm start, everything seems to work fine, but when I connect to the DNS for the EC2 to try and view the website on port:3000, it crashes.

This is the error I get in the EC2 console: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F91J3.jpg)

I understand that there's an issue with the docs variable in the index.js file, I just don't know how to fix it, the db connection seems to be working, I've verified the entries are in the db on the linux server, plus the exact same code is working in windows with no problem and was yesterday on linux as well.

The code below is the contents of the index.js file, but the entire project is on git if you need any more information.

https://github.com/colegil2012/PhotographyWebsiteMEAN

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Photo = require('../models/photo.js');


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    Photo.find({ galleryHeader: true },function (err, docs) {
      var photoChunks = [];
      var chunkSize = 3;
      for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i += chunkSize) {
        photoChunks.push(docs.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
      }
        res.render('photoSite/index', {title: 'Luminosity Photography', 
photos: photoChunks});
    });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Thanks for any help guys

Comment: docs isn't being returned as an array, so either you need to check the err to make sure docs has values in it, also if find doesn't find any record what does it return? not sure if it returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docs in `for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i += chunkSize)`seems to be undefined, an error might have occurred which is not being handled.
I suggest you handle the error case as well.
You may include an if-then-else case as follows:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    Photo.find({ galleryHeader: true },function (err, docs) {
      if(err){
        //handle error case
      } else {
        var photoChunks = [];
        var chunkSize = 3;
        for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i += chunkSize) {
          photoChunks.push(docs.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
        }
        res.render('photoSite/index', {title: 'Luminosity Photography', 
photos: photoChunks});
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, I did try this and just added a do nothing for if there is an err, that did get the website to pull up, just with none of the galleries, I feel like there has to be something outdated in the mongo connections? I tried reverting to an earlier version of mongoose and mongodb, but it didn't seem to help. It's just confusing because everything works perfectly fine locally on windows, it's only when I upload the files to the EC2 Ubuntu instance that these problems occur.

Comment: When I run the seed file for mongodb it doesn't inject any of the data in the table, so I manually added all the entries but then it's still not pulling the data to populate the docs array.